# How can one manipulate an data nested private classES over using friend function

Tags: c++, class, struct, friend

```
       class Hen {
            friend class Nest ;
            class Nest {
                    int n ;
                    friend class Egg;
                    class Egg {
                         int e ;
                    } *eg;
            } *nst ;
            public :
                friend void fill (  **!** ) ;
                ... // some code to show data
       };
```

1. if `**!** = Nest *;` using that function, How can I manipulate data in Egg?
2. if `**!** = Egg *;` using that function, How can I manipulate data in Nest?

Note : I have tried and searched in internet but I could not find any answer. So, I am asking there, if these question is trivial, forgive me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the outer class a friend of the nested class:

```
class Hen {             
    class Nest {
    friend class Hen;
        class Egg {
        friend class Nest;
        };
    };
};
```